# Developing ASP.Net User Control to be imported to SharePoint MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, user-controls, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

Apologies if this has been answered, but I could not find a similar question:

I am developing a webpart for MOSS 2007.  I am using WSPBuilder to built a visual webpart (ascx) and everything works fine, but the development/debug cycle is just painfully slow, so I'd like to know if it is possible (without being too painful) to develop the user control faster using an .Net Web Application project with all of the nice F5 debugging, then import the final product into my SharePoint visual webpart.

The user control interacts with a LOB system (SQL) and does not reference the SharePoint API at all. (The reason I am building this as a webpart is because I don't need another web app to run this one page, so putting it into a webpart on a new webpart page on my existing site is the best solution IMO.)  I would obviously need to import (reference?) my data access classes into my "temp" web app, but think that would not be too much trouble.

I realize this will be extra effort to get this set up, but am thinking the payoff will be reduced development time of the actual user control using a little web application vs having to use the compile/build WSP/deploy WSP/reset ISS/test/make a change/repeat cycle that MOSS requires.  (I guess SP2010/VS2010 has spoiled me with the native SharePoint tools available.)

> Update:
>
> I have successfully built a simple web app with one page and loaded up my UC on the page.  (I had to comment out all of the Sharepoint Import and register statements that WSP Builder added to the UC for me when I created the webpart.) I added references to my utility classes (which I left in the obj\Debug folder in the original SharePoint project).  It took me a while tinkering with everything to get it to work, but the steps ended up being pretty simple and I think I can replicate the steps quickly for future projects.  Once it was set up, I was able to rapidly design the UC and build in the UC functionality using the typical F5 debug cycle.  Unless someone can show me why this is not a good idea, I plan to repeat this for future projects!  Thanks to everyone for thier input.

.

> Update 2
>
> Well, I am not sure what I did but moving the UC back into SharePoint proved to be troublesome.  The first time I did it, I spent several hours getting it to work in SharePoint, making me question whether it was worth it.  However, I am stubborn and tried it again.  This time, I only copied and pasted the markup below the "header section" (the part with all of the <%@ . . . %> statements) in the ascx file and everything went perfectly.  I think I must have changed something inadvertantly the first time.  I think I will continue this pattern as it is so much faster to build and test the UC in an ASP.NET web app.  (Again, this only works if you are not referencing the Sharepoint API anywhere in the UC.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer here is the [SmartPart](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/). It is perfect for just the scenario you are describing. Very easy to create a Usercontrol using "vanilla" ASP.NET and have it work as a webpart in SharePoint. I've outlined the steps to migrate from ASP.NET webpage to statically bound SmartPart on [my blog](http://www.mobiusdevelopment.com/dev/Blog.asp?ArticleID=5268401986879274349).

Comment: The process you outline in your blog is almost exactly what I am trying to achieve.  I am comfortable with building SP webparts that use a UC, but am curious if there is an advantage to building the UC outside of the SharePoint dev cycle and then dropping it in later.  Specifically, are the time savings from developing the UC in an ASP.NET development environment worth the extra effort needed to drop the UC into a SP webpart.  Unless I am missing something, it looks like this might be a good approach to reduce the total development time.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you intend to achieve is surely a nice idea.

Just remember to strong name your user control, drop it in your Server's GAC, update SafeControls section of your SharePoint 80's web.config.

All these setps are one off, after each successive builds (of your web control), you have to just deploy the control (used forcede deploy) in GAC and reset IIS.

You can add this control to toolbox in VS by selecting 'Choose Items' and selecting ther assembly you just deployed.

In addition you can create a test ASP.NET page to test the functionality of your control.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is that once the usercontrol is working that way I want, I'll drop it into a Visual Webpart project that has already been built with other webparts for the same project.  After adjusting some namespaces, I think WSPbuilder will take care of the rest of the steps you listed. (This is a one-off webpart, so I wouldn't need it in the toolbox, but it's nice to see how that could be done!)  Thanks for the help.